# Printing a subtotal when a value is defined inside an if-elif-else statement? Name error issue [Python 2.7]

Tags: python, if-statement, undefined, nameerror

I'm currently working on a project which acts as an airline reservation booking system.  As of right now I'm having an issue with calculating and displaying a subtotal which was calculated inside of an if elif else loop statement, if that makes sense.

For example, I currently need to calculate the subtotal of the seats and luggage.  Below is my code:

```
user_people = int(raw_input("Welcome to Ramirez Airlines!  How many people will be flying?"))
user_seating = str(raw_input("Perfect!  Now what type of seating would your party prefer?"))
user_luggage = int(raw_input("Thanks.  Now for your luggage, how many bags would you like to check in?"))
user_frequent = str(raw_input("Got it.  Is anyone in your party a frequent flyer with us?"))
user_continue = str(raw_input("Your reservation was submitted successfully.  Would you like to do another?"))
luggage_total = user_luggage * 50


import time
print time.strftime("Date and time confirmation: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

if user_seating == 'economy':
    seats_total = user_people * 916
    print seats_total

elif user_seating == 'business':
    seats_total = user_people * 2650
    print seats_total

else: 
    print user_people * 5180

print luggage_total

print luggage_total + seats_total
```

As I said above I'm trying to add the total price for the number of plane tickets reserved based on which class the user chose (economy, business and first class) and the total amount of the required luggage needed to be checked in (x amount & $50).

This is the error I am receiving when executing the above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Cory/Desktop/Project 1.py", line 26, in <module>
    print luggage_total + seats_total
NameError: name 'seats_total' is not defined
```

How do I go about defining seats_total outside of the if-elif-else statements?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Whoops was a mistake, sorry about that.  It's Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your variable `seats_total` will be defined only for `user_seating == 'economy'` or `user_seating == 'business'`. For the third case, no such variable is defined. To define "seats_total outside of the if-elif-else statements" just set it to zero for example, or some default value.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response!  I understand what you just said above but how would I go about adding seats_total to luggage_total then depending on which case the user chose for seating type?  All of them are inside the if-elif-else statements.

Comment: The default value of e.g. zero, would be overwritten in the if statements.

Comment: Okay so you're saying I can just declare seats_total = 0, either before or after the if statements, and it'd work?

Comment: `seats_total = 0` must go before the if statements.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help. If so, accepting the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @CoryRamirez Yes, while loop is good to ask user for his input, or to ask again if the his input is incorrect, e.g. integer instead of string, etc.